# How can I host ASP.NET 5 (vNext) MVC 6 project under IIS classic mode pool

Tags: iis-7, httphandler, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Made a package using `kpm pack`
Tried to set up IIS7 in classic pipeline mode

I keep receiving

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.
```

Already tried to

- add aspnet_isapi.dll to `web.config/system.webServer/handlers` section
- add `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` for `web.config/system.webServer/handlers` section

All aspnet_isapi.dll in ISAPI and CGI restrictions are allowed

Is hosting vNext ASP.NET application under IIS classic mode pipeline possible?

Comment: I can only get it working in integrated mode. Why are you trying to use classic? also I think the error message is: The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the ISAPI and CGI Restriction list settings on the Web server.

Comment: I also get it working only in integrated mode.

Comment: @yhax classic mode support is kind of our environment requirements. Updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per current development I think this is not working in Classic IIS Mode. It will only work in IIS Integrated mode.

Give me few reason.

1. Till ASP.net MVC 5 request processing is done through MVC Handler and it is not integrated with pipeline like OWIN.
2. In ASP.net vnext (MVC6) request processing is more or like OWIN. It is like tightly integrated with integrated piplline of IIS ( In Katana it will give you error if you run in Classic mode)